# Convert watches elasticsearch output to json with groovy

Tags: json, elasticsearch, groovy, kibana

I want to convert **payload.hits.hits** to json in elasticsearch watcher output. I found as a solution groovy transform script :

```
PUT _watcher/watch/error_alert
{
"trigger": {
  "schedule": {
  "interval": "1m"
}
},
"input": {
"search": {
  "request": {
    "body": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "query_string": {
                "default_field": "message",
                "query": "ERROR"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "gte": "now-1m",
                  "lte": "now"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
},
"condition": {
  "compare": {
    "ctx.payload.hits.total": {
      "gt": 0
  }
 }
 },
"transform" : {
    "script" : "return [ body:  groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(ctx.payload.hits.hits)]"
},
"actions": {
"some_webhook": {
  "webhook": {
    "method": "POST",
    "host": "*.*.*.*",
    "port": 4000,
    "path": "/sms",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": "message: {{ctx.payload.body}}"
  }
}
}
}
```

This request returns this exception:

```
    "type": "general_script_exception",
    "reason": "failed to compile script [ScriptException[compile error]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Variable [body] is not defined.];]"
```

I have tried many alternative solutions but it seems that it works for most of people except me!

I use:

- Elasticsearch **5.3.0**
- Kibana 5.0.2

Can someone help me please !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a syntax issue in your json.

```
"return [ body:  groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(ctx.payload.hits.hits)]"
```

Try

```
"return { 'body':  JsonOutput.toJson(ctx.payload.hits.hits)}"
```

Comment: it returns : **IllegalArgumentException[Variable [groovy] is not defined.];**

Comment: You need to enable groovy. Set the following in your elasticsearch.yml file
script.engine.groovy.inline.search: on

Comment: On second thought it looks like groovy IS enabled, but I'm not sure you can get json from calling groovy.json.JsonOutput have you tried just calling JsonOutput ?